# Linq strategy for complex set

Tags: sql, linq, entity-framework

Am developing a ViewModel/PresentationModel which is getting complex.

I want the Linq query to return an `IQueryable<UserPresentationModel>`

Using EntityFramework against MSSQL

Is it possible to do any sort of iteration over the set before returning it to the presentation layer ie

```
            List<UserPresentationModel> list = new List<UserPresentationModel>();
            foreach (var person in listOfPeople)
            {
                UserPresentationModel u = new UserPresentationModel();
                int userUIStatus = GetColourStateOfPerson(person);
                u.FirstName = person.FirstName;
                u.UserUIStatus = userUIStatus;
                list.Add(u);
            }
            return list
```

This feels like it would always be N+1, and I'd never get the advantages of deferred execution, composing of queries..

Or (and I think am answering my own question) do I need to think in a SQL set based manner.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, we can convert your code to LINQ.

```
IEnumerable<UserPresentationModel> models =
    from person in listOfPeople
    select new UserPresentationModel
    {
        FirstName = person.FirstName,
        UserUIStatus = GetColourStateOfPerson(person)
    }

return models.ToList();
```

Now, if `GetColourStateOfPerson` is making a DB round-trip, you definitely want to pull that out.

```
IDictionary<int, int> colourStatesByPersonId = GetColourStatesOfPeople(listOfPeople);
IEnumerable<UserPresentationModel> models =
    from person in listOfPeople
    select new UserPresentationModel
    {
        FirstName = person.FirstName,
        UserUIStatus = colourStatesByPersonId[person.PersonId]
    }

return models.ToList();
```

You could probably manage to create a single LINQ query that grabs just the first names and colour states of the people you want in a single query, but you haven't provided enough information about your data context for me to help you with that.

I would personally avoid passing around an IQueryable, which could continue making database trips any time somebody touches it. Let your data layer get out all the data you're likely to need, compose it into a list, and return that.

Comment: Thanks StriplingWarrior - very useful to strip out the GetColourStatesOfPeople and return using the dictionary above.  Makes testing much easier when can break down large queries!

Answer (score 0):

use `IEnumerable<T>.Aggregate()` instead of looping.

```
return listOfPeople.Aggregate(new List<UserPresentationModel>(), person => {
    return new UserPresentationModel {
         FirstName = person.FirstName,
         UserUIStatus = GetColourStateOfPerson(person)
    };
}).AsQueryable();
```

Comment: Why use Aggregate? This only needs to be a `Select`. If the `List` aspect is important, call `ToList`.

Comment: You are correct. `Select` would be more appropriate. All linq operations can be performed with only the `Aggregate` method. I am catching myself over using it as of late.

Answer (score 0):

```
return listOfPeople.AsEnumerable().Select(p => 
    new UserPresentationModel
    {
        FirstName = p.FirstName,
        UserUIStatus = GetColourStateOfPerson(p)
    }).AsQueryable();
```

I'm assuming that `listOfPeople` is an `IQueryable` that will eventually execute against your database.  If that is the case then `AsEnumerable()` is important because SQL Server won't know what to do with `GetColourStateOfPerson()`.  `AsEnumerable()` will force the `IQueryable`'s expression tree to execute, pull the resulting rows out of your database and then apply `Select()` transformation in code as oppose to in SQL Server.

If you can implement `GetColourStateOfPerson()` as a stored proc or database function then you can omit `AsEnumerable()` and `AsQueryable()` and allow execution to delay even longer.

Comment: Thanks Ray - am keeping as much logic in code rather than SP/Fn..mainly for future readability and findability.